# Google App-Engine block incoming traffic by country?

Tags: .htaccess, google-app-engine

I'm looking into developing a system via Google's App Engine for PHP.  I'm now pretty well underway, but realized that I don't know a good way to deny incoming traffic from countries known for their nefarious inhabitants.

On other sites, I just block subnets via .htaccess.  However, I'm now beginning to think it's impossible outside of using Google's own PHP request header designating the country code.

[See their doc here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/)

It would be easy to just block it that way, but I'm not sure this would be the optimal way.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try CloudFlare service? DNS your domain to CloudFlare, they have very good firewall that you can config what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. Just a quick note that our country block option in Threat Control currently only provides a challenge page & isn't a full block (may be able to do this in the future). It is, however, very effective at stopping bots.

Note: The reason it currently works like this is that site owners probably want to block bots and not humans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`dos.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/dosref) file to blacklist subnets. You create a `dos.yaml` file in the root directory of your application and then block IPs or entire subnets as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/dos#subnet). Note that this file is limited to a maximum of 100 entries.

Once you have a list of country subnets which you wish to block (which you could obtain from a list like [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/) or [this](https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker)), you can populate the `dos.yaml` file manually. Alternatively, you can use [a script like this one](https://gist.github.com/mdornseif/6682539#file-ddos-py) to populate the file.

Comment: this is so awesome!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the DOS attack protection mentioned in @rudolph1024's answer it is now possible to enable a fully-featured firewall (still beta, recently released) to protect your GAE application.

From [App Engine firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/application-security#app_engine_firewall):

> The App Engine firewall enables you to control access to your App
>   Engine app through a set of rules that can either allow or deny
>   requests from the specified ranges of IP addresses.
>
> Create a firewall to:
>
> - **Allow only traffic from within a specific network**
>
>   Ensure that only a certain range of IP addresses from specific networks can access your app. For example, create rules to allow only
>     the range of IP addresses from within your company's private network
>     during your app's testing phase. You can then create and modify your
>     firewall rules to control the scope of access throughout your release
>     process, allowing only certain organizations, either within your
>     company or externally, to access your app as it makes it's way to
>     public availability.
> - **Allow only traffic from a specific service**
>
>   Ensure that all the traffic to your App Engine app is first proxied through a specific service. For example, if you use a
>     third-party Web Application Firewall (WAF) to proxy requests directed
>     at your app, you can create firewall rules to deny all requests except
>     those that are forwarded from your WAF.
> - **Block abusive IP addresses**
>
>   While Google Cloud Platform has many mechanisms in place to prevent the various attacks, you can use the App Engine firewall as
>     another mechanism to block traffic to your app from IP addresses that
>     present malicious intent.
>
>   You should use the App Engine firewall as your primary option for
>     shielding your app from denial of service attacks or similar forms of
>     abuse. You can blacklist IP addresses or subnets so that requests
>     routed from those addresses and subnets are denied before it reaches
>     your App Engine app.
>
> For details about creating rules and configuring your firewall, see
>   [Controlling App Access with Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls).

The firewall appears to be intended to replace the DOS protection. From [Denial of service (DoS) protection service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/application-security#denial_of_service_dos_protection_service):

> **Tip:** You should instead use the [App Engine firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/application-security#app_engine_firewall) for reliable protection as well as the improved features, access, and
>   management through the Cloud Platform Console, **gcloud** command-line
>   tool, and Admin API.

You still need to collect the IP ranges for the country in your particular case, to configure the firewall.