# Is there a way to ban IP addresses from accessing my parse-server?

Tags: google-app-engine, parse-server

If a particular computer is making tons of accounts or flooding my server with other requests, could parse-server automatically check this behaviour and block the specified IP address?

Built-in rate limiting would also be a nice alternative, although it doesn't really solve the problem if the person continues to spam.

I am hosting on google app engine by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Parse itself, but from App Engine side you have [DoS protection service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dos) controlled via `dos.yaml` file in your project that lets you blacklist IP blocks—sounds like that may help. It's not "automatic", though; you still need to manually update this file and issue `appcfg.py update_dos <PROJECT_DIR>` for changes to take effect.

Comment: It looks like dynamic ip restrictions are missing from GAE, despite being possible on AWS, Azure, or any individual load balancer (HAProxy, etc). Such a shame, it makes GAE not very viable imo.

Comment: FWIW GAE firewall was recently released, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682114/google-app-engine-block-incoming-traffic-by-country/45891423#45891423

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is a feature out of the box - see advanced options here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server.

You'd need to look at controlling access to the Google App Engine (or another host - such as Microsoft Azure Web App) using a firewall (you can easily do this with Azure.  I'm not familiar with Google App Engine, but imagine similar functionality is available.

However, I don't believe that a firewall is necessary - just better app security. Disable anonymous users - [Parse Server Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657486/parse-server-security)